# javascript override class variable

Tags: javascript, frappe

I have class with variables, I want change variable value by another function in external file

Class code

```
frappe.ui.Notifications = class Notifications {
    constructor() {
        frappe.model
            .with_doc('Notification Settings', frappe.session.user)
            .then(doc => {
                this.notifications_settings = doc;
                this.make();
            });
    }

    make() {
        this.$dropdown = $('.navbar').find('.dropdown-notifications');
        this.$dropdown_list = this.$dropdown.find('.notifications-list');
        this.$notification_indicator = this.$dropdown.find('.notifications-indicator');
    }
};
```

i wand change variable `this.$dropdown`

```
frappe.ui.Notifications.$dropdown =  $('.Header').find('.dropdown-item-notifications');
```

Comment: Any answers or solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Notification class instance is set at `frappe.frappe_toolbar.notifications`. You can use it to override the property.

```js
frappe.frappe_toolbar.notifications.$dropdown = $('.Header').find('.dropdown-item-notifications');
```